# ruby 1.8.7 undefined local variable

Tags: ruby

I have two files:

```
# wordlist.rb
code_words = {
    'computer' => 'devil worshipping device',
    'penny' => 'pretty',
    'decoration' => 'girlandes, green light bulbs, skeletons',
    'pets' => 'captured souls'
}
```

and

```
# confidant.rb
require 'wordlist'

# Get string and swap in code words
print 'Say your piece: 
'

idea = gets
code_words.each do |original, translated|
    idea.gsub! original, translated
end

# Save the translated idea to a new file
print 'File encoded. Please enter a name for your piece: 
'

piece_name = gets.strip
File::open 'piece-' + piece_name + '.txt', 'w' do |f|
    f << idea
end
```

running ruby confidant.rb results in an error message:

> confidant.rb:12: undefined local variable or method 'code_words' for
>   main:Object (NameError)

Do I have to qualify code_words somehow? The code is a slightly adapted example from _why's poignant guide.

Comment: Thanks to the both for the answers.

Comment: You should use `puts` instead of `print` if you are going to have a newline at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, local variables from other files aren't pulled in. You could remedy this by making `code_words` into a global variable (e.g., `CODE_WORDS`) and then changing it accordingly in `confidant.rb`

Comment: Good enough, since this is an example.

Comment: `CODE_WORDS` would be a global constant.  If you want a global variable so you can modify it later, call it `$code_words`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use instance variable here (with `@` sign)

```
# wordlist.rb
@code_words = {
    'computer' => 'devil worshipping device',
    'penny' => 'pretty',
    'decoration' => 'girlandes, green light bulbs, skeletons',
    'pets' => 'captured souls'
}
```

Comment: Usually I'd go with your answer, but in this example, I think that'd be overkill (which would go with the level of analysis going into the sample, but hey, I'm learning)